# No DbContext was found in assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, entity-framework

I am a frontend developer. Another developer gave me a working code base.

I run these commands for setup:

```
dotnet restore
sh setup_script.sh
```

Where `setup_script.sh` contains:

```
export password=root
export database=localdb
docker rm --force $database
docker run --name $database -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$password -e POSTGRES_DB=$database -p 5431:5432 -d postgres
cd src/Server
dotnet ef database update
```

I get this error:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider.
>
> One or more errors occurred. (Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret). No DbContext was found in assembly 'Server'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

I used VS Code extension "AWS Toolkit", inside credentials files I wrote access and secret keys with I created in related to project aws account (IAM service). I see some files in S3, that means that I have wrote right keys.

When I tried to run:

```
dotnet run
```

I got the same error but with detailed info that error on next line:

```
response = client.GetSecretValueAsync(request).Result;
```

Passing context of that line:

```
public static string GetSecret(string secretName)
{
    string region = "eu-central-1";
    string secret = "";

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    IAmazonSecretsManager client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));

    GetSecretValueRequest request = new GetSecretValueRequest();
    request.SecretId = secretName;
    request.VersionStage = "AWSCURRENT";
    GetSecretValueResponse? response = null;

    try
    {
        response = client.GetSecretValueAsync(request).Result;
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```

Hope somebody will help! I am ready to provide additional info.